# Mac versus PC differences with lsmeans/nlme in R?

Tags: r, windows, macos, nlme, lsmeans

I am having two problems, that are apparently related:

- Firstly, lsmeans in R is giving me two different outputs when run on Mac
  versus PC.
- Secondly, the script works outside of a function on both PC and Mac.
  However, it will not work inside a function on Mac.

I have been wrestling with this project for weeks and I am at my wits end trying to make it work.

Some background:

- The experimental data is from state wide research trials, with
  multiple years and locations.
- The script is being built into functions that automatically generate
  output for specified subsets of the data.
- The raw data and functions are being shared via Box Sync, and need to
  be accessed and used by multiple people using both Mac and PC.
- I am opening identical data and script on both computers, both
  computers run R 3.3. All packages have been updated to the latest version.

Here is example data:

```
df<-structure(list(YEAR=structure(c(3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L),.Label=c("2014","2015","2016"),class="factor"),
LOCATION=structure(c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
1L,1L,1L,1L),.Label="KERN",class="factor"),LAT=c(35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,35.3695756,
35.3695756,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,
35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.394386,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,
35.137156,35.137156,35.137156,35.137156),LONG=c(-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,-119.3332198,
-119.3332198,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,-119.341943,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,-119.032647,
-119.032647,-119.032647),PLOT_NUM=c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,
6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,16L,17L,18L,
19L,20L,21L,22L,23L,24L,25L,26L,27L,28L,29L,30L,
31L,32L,33L,34L,35L,36L,37L,38L,39L,40L,41L,42L,
43L,44L,45L,46L,47L,48L,49L,50L,51L,52L,53L,54L,
55L,56L,57L,58L,59L,60L,61L,62L,63L,64L,65L,66L,
67L,68L,69L,70L,71L,72L,73L,74L,75L,76L,77L,78L,
79L,80L,81L,82L,83L,84L,85L,86L,87L,88L,89L,90L,
91L,92L,93L,94L,95L,96L,97L,98L,99L,100L,101L,
102L,103L,104L,105L,106L,107L,108L,109L,110L,111L,
112L,134L,136L,104L,92L,135L,27L,4L,71L,122L,91L,
59L,90L,102L,69L,26L,38L,7L,58L,70L,101L,133L,
124L,39L,121L,60L,28L,29L,123L,37L,36L,103L,6L,
5L,42L,75L,56L,107L,22L,24L,106L,88L,40L,118L,
23L,25L,11L,9L,57L,55L,10L,86L,89L,139L,41L,74L,
119L,73L,43L,105L,8L,137L,72L,120L,138L,87L,54L,
115L,85L,52L,109L,83L,141L,77L,47L,79L,82L,117L,
78L,21L,12L,13L,14L,142L,108L,44L,20L,51L,84L,
76L,116L,110L,19L,46L,18L,140L,50L,15L,53L,45L,
281L,200L,291L,198L,192L,232L,196L,301L,289L,279L,
302L,243L,251L,230L,207L,199L,220L,186L,277L,303L,
187L,197L,247L,205L,255L,257L,188L,305L,260L,269L,
278L,245L,299L,222L,218L,204L,308L,288L,290L,307L,
248L,272L,280L,203L,297L,228L,201L,214L,194L,246L,
233L,227L,286L,263L,250L,275L,261L,253L,231L,271L,
221L,287L,270L,224L,190L,234L,226L,276L,216L,256L,
191L,189L,195L,258L,292L,284L,219L,242L,282L,273L,
235L,283L,304L,262L,252L,229L,300L,254L,259L,298L,
306L,274L,206L,249L,202L,217L,225L,285L,215L,223L,
193L,244L),ENTRY_NUM=structure(c(20L,14L,51L,42L,
48L,45L,44L,46L,8L,43L,9L,45L,46L,8L,18L,9L,15L,
52L,51L,42L,50L,46L,49L,47L,19L,43L,50L,36L,12L,
8L,47L,10L,6L,21L,8L,10L,2L,48L,17L,49L,12L,20L,
13L,43L,19L,13L,45L,22L,47L,17L,15L,36L,18L,52L,
6L,48L,46L,15L,18L,22L,13L,7L,50L,18L,19L,7L,
2L,44L,47L,51L,22L,6L,7L,10L,14L,44L,36L,52L,
2L,22L,10L,19L,49L,21L,7L,45L,44L,2L,14L,9L,51L,
15L,12L,20L,21L,42L,52L,17L,48L,50L,36L,14L,6L,
49L,21L,43L,12L,20L,13L,9L,17L,42L,1L,2L,3L,4L,
5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,17L,18L,
19L,20L,21L,22L,24L,28L,29L,30L,36L,37L,38L,39L,
40L,41L,42L,44L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,
11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,17L,18L,19L,20L,21L,22L,24L,
28L,29L,30L,36L,37L,38L,39L,40L,41L,42L,44L,1L,
2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,11L,12L,13L,14L,
15L,17L,18L,19L,20L,21L,22L,24L,28L,29L,30L,36L,
37L,38L,39L,40L,41L,42L,44L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,
3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,5L,5L,5L,6L,6L,6L,7L,7L,7L,
8L,8L,8L,9L,9L,9L,11L,11L,11L,12L,12L,12L,13L,
13L,13L,14L,14L,14L,15L,15L,15L,16L,16L,16L,17L,
17L,17L,18L,18L,18L,19L,19L,19L,20L,20L,20L,21L,
21L,21L,22L,22L,22L,23L,23L,23L,24L,24L,24L,25L,
25L,25L,26L,26L,26L,27L,27L,27L,28L,28L,28L,29L,
29L,29L,30L,30L,30L,31L,31L,31L,32L,32L,32L,33L,
33L,33L,34L,34L,34L,35L,35L,35L),.Label=c("878",
"951","1166","1210","1211","1215","1375","1429","1431",
"1440","1473","1479","1484","1582","1583","1585","1607",
"1627","1640","1654","1690","1697","1698","1721","1733",
"1756","1758","1770","1771","1776","1782","1783","1784",
"1785","1786","1796","1797","1798","1799","1800","1801",
"1810","1812","1813","1822","1823","1824","1825","1826",
"1827","1832","1833"),class="factor"),BLOCK=c(1L,
1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,
4L,3L,3L,3L,3L,2L,2L,2L,2L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,2L,2L,2L,2L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,
2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,3L,3L,
3L,2L,2L,2L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,
3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,3L,3L,3L,2L,
2L,2L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,
2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,
4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,
4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,
1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,
1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,
1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,
1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,
1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,
1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,
1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L,1L,2L,3L),YIELD=c(6161.570159,
5560.05164,5027.418215,6479.200167,5741.388915,7172.181818,
4689.599352,5987.74792,5666.825975,6071.348724,5478.883003,
7124.783728,5656.242954,3610.181643,4331.324396,4904.546884,
4447.489172,4106.787872,4658.348018,6259.997274,6153.207065,
6313.497876,5676.779979,5357.37221,6466.719177,6230.109145,
6688.341036,6442.7157,6100.712992,4621.929508,5755.886769,
6604.254137,4954.200669,5867.5903,3991.831947,6005.947762,
6650.642431,5068.746236,3389.123183,4665.019064,5061.072647,
4478.621635,3941.029714,4229.627327,5402.926203,4245.353341,
5637.312903,5518.179277,4389.871419,4215.083338,4897.365913,
6086.120238,4502.709961,5024.207751,5723.2024,4795.406733,
5589.303172,4157.52343,4694.93871,5977.432504,4828.809253,
4207.050908,5533.320623,3808.889598,5191.0883,5565.5,
5967.716748,4695.892909,3745.651761,2326.036846,5520.691951,
3616.957981,6062.2518,5539.725094,4599.123634,4539.368454,
6400.747636,3883.129209,6770.653931,6197.140663,5676.23605,
5778.724469,5696.726085,4583.617968,4006.825885,5611.114514,
5077.577925,6096.838084,3900.072863,4227.004389,3784.270665,
4244.82975,5221.064527,6211.31643,5790.782248,6239.067852,
2557.838189,2827.312193,3869.848855,4470.534568,7274.162574,
5137.88216,6012.906525,5530.157816,6173.018569,5228.493966,
5781.589525,5887.075038,5244.684963,5063.663862,4275.956581,
5568.79725,6649.127517,4069.433962,5760,5241.904762,
5195.294118,5482.105263,7206.233766,5491.2,4979.2,6739.328859,
5202.162162,5734.736842,6568.421053,6227.027027,5296.107383,
5222.4,4458.947368,5564.081633,6829.530201,6778.77551,
6973.333333,5667.945205,5942.857143,6044.903226,6349.803922,
6101.917808,7069.090909,5682.162162,5476.510067,5220.392157,
5166.315789,6669.473684,6055.384615,6233.6,4869.933775,
5733.146853,4718.873239,4746.335404,5397.482517,6014.304636,
5681.632653,7018.378378,6003.2,4618.039216,7048.767123,
5409.811321,6632.727273,5952,4966.4,5322.531646,5423.376623,
6662.781457,5823.157895,7210.06993,5216.842105,6063.157895,
7000.816327,5687.088608,6896.326531,6630.4,5734.228188,
6136.470588,4522.95302,5446.27451,5987.368421,5060.662252,
5027.913669,5844.528302,4882.285714,5169.230769,5290.06993,
4463.046358,5570.704225,5106.938776,6088.767123,5435.492958,
4940.8,6170.482759,5368.421053,6048.627451,6006.486486,
4539.428571,5347.555556,6637.350993,6271.168831,5838.367347,
6057.464789,5018.482759,6498.461538,5450.738255,6168.510638,
5106.666667,6404.475524,5357.837838,4850.526316,3458.630137,
4717.350993,5859.74026,5354.366197,7409.079755,6442.105263,
7450,6203.076923,6362.790698,6693.333333,7211.707317,
7481.806452,6858.666667,7572.670807,8274.285714,7886.769231,
6328.888889,6395.761589,6507.789474,6295.272727,6681.156069,
6965.106383,7521.019108,9086.369427,8196.923077,5969.454545,
5376,6107.234043,5934.545455,6514.682081,7135.828877,
5954.43038,5539.459459,5513.142857,5701.818182,6594.206897,
7101.176471,8905.030675,6950.614525,8660.425532,7515.092025,
7316.078431,6471.111111,3473.121019,4295.028902,5422.417582,
6970.181818,7819.441341,8506.490066,5772.715232,5268.837209,
5335.578947,7600.941176,8048.813559,6842.553191,7773.658537,
8278.441558,7326.315789,7333.012048,7232,6662.295082,
8436.363636,7949.662921,7182.222222,9399.215686,8777.142857,
7222.38342,8258.313253,7755.505618,7975.384615,6864,
7437.241379,7251.06383,7655.541401,7718.145695,7926.857143,
7959.493671,8582.013423,8792.275862,5636.923077,6573.774834,
7036.595745,8457.423313,6860.8,8353.507853,7821.349693,
9017.142857,8494.545455,7289.101796,7855.542857,7302.47191,
7917.037037,8035.955056,8543.492063,6984,5975.730337,
7298.931298,8024.615385,7200,7923.380282,7749.818182,
6758.843931,8354.198473,1110.943396,1356.8,1421.837838
),PROTEIN=c(15.03867,14.82126,15.748876,15.437255,
16.589528,14.640085,16.575034,15.582195,15.524219,14.973447,
15.408267,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,15.002435,16.792444,17.343216,
15.770617,15.734382,15.212598,14.995188,16.219931,15.47349,
15.524219,15.567701,15.879322,15.198104,17.002607,15.661912,
15.03867,16.430094,15.959039,17.162041,14.828507,15.502478,
16.988113,17.633096,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,16.05325,15.25608,
15.190857,16.915643,17.517144,15.937298,15.567701,16.748962,
16.082238,16.647504,16.99536,15.632924,16.248919,17.335969,
15.306809,16.661998,16.857667,15.988027,17.437427,15.748876,
15.814099,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,14.379193,16.495317,
15.828593,16.328636,15.285068,15.357538,15.451749,15.785111,
15.321303,16.517058,16.980866,15.379279,16.473576,15.487984,
15.922804,17.379451,16.872161,15.560454,15.83584,15.705394,
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,16.843173,15.089399,16.212684,
15.937298,15.683653,15.959039,16.234425,15.966286,17.28524,
16.183696,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,11.56,NA,
NA,12.07,NA,NA,11.4,NA,NA,11.7,NA,NA,11.3,NA,
NA,12.07,NA,NA,12.5,NA,NA,12.57,NA,NA,12.08,NA,
NA,11.87,NA,NA,12.37,NA,NA,11.26,NA,NA,11.3,NA,
NA,11.32,NA,NA,11.98,NA,NA,12,NA,NA,11.99,NA,
NA,11.53,NA,NA,11.82,NA,NA,12.16,NA,NA,10.82,NA,
NA,10.3,NA,NA,11.24,NA,NA,10.79,NA,NA,11.17,NA,
NA,13.06,NA,NA,11.07,NA,NA,11.65,NA,NA,12,NA,
NA,10.26,NA,NA,11.38,NA,NA,10.61,NA,NA,11.24,NA,
NA,14.12,NA,NA)),.Names=c("YEAR","LOCATION","LAT",
"LONG","PLOT_NUM","ENTRY_NUM","BLOCK","YIELD","PROTEIN"),row.names=c(NA,
-313L),class="data.frame")
```

Data setup:

```
df$ENTRY_NUM <- as.factor(df$ENTRY_NUM)
df$YEAR <- as.factor(df$YEAR)
df$LOCATION <- as.factor(df$LOCATION)
df$BLOCK <- as.factor(df$BLOCK)

require(nlme)
require(lsmeans)
```

Generating lsmeans estimates across all years of data. This works fine on PC and Mac both in and out of a function.

```
m.lme <- lme((PROTEIN) ~ ENTRY_NUM,
             data = df, random = ~1|YEAR/LOCATION,
             na.action = na.exclude)

org.lsm <- lsmeans(m.lme, "ENTRY_NUM")
YIELD.lsm <<- data.frame(summary(org.lsm))

# A function to do the same thing.

Data_3Yr <- df

Three_yr_fn_Y <- function(Data_3Yr) 
{

  m.lme <- lme((PROTEIN) ~ ENTRY_NUM,
               data = df, random = ~1|YEAR/LOCATION,
               na.action = na.exclude)

  org.lsm <- lsmeans(m.lme, "ENTRY_NUM")
  YIELD.lsm <<- data.frame(summary(org.lsm))
}

ThreeYear_r <- Three_yr_fn_Y(Data_3Yr)
```

The single years is where it starts to fail. The data is subset by year, and each year is run to get an lsmeans table. This works fine on Mac and PC. However, when each year is run in a function on a Mac it fails.

```
# Individual years.
Y1 <- subset(df, YEAR == "2014")
Y2 <- subset(df, YEAR == "2015")
Y3 <- subset(df, YEAR == "2016")

# These all work fine for me.
# Single years
Data_1Yr <- Y1

m.lme <- lme((YIELD) ~ ENTRY_NUM,
             data = Data_1Yr, random = ~1|LOCATION/BLOCK,
             #weights = varPower(form = ~fitted(.)),
             na.action = na.exclude)

org.lsm <- lsmeans(m.lme, "ENTRY_NUM")
YIELD.lsm <- data.frame(summary(org.lsm))

Data_1Yr <- Y2

m.lme <- lme((YIELD) ~ ENTRY_NUM,
             data = Data_1Yr, random = ~1|LOCATION/BLOCK,
             #weights = varPower(form = ~fitted(.)),
             na.action = na.exclude)

org.lsm <- lsmeans(m.lme, "ENTRY_NUM")
YIELD.lsm <- data.frame(summary(org.lsm))

Data_1Yr <- Y3

m.lme <- lme((YIELD) ~ ENTRY_NUM,
             data = Data_1Yr, random = ~1|LOCATION/BLOCK,
             #weights = varPower(form = ~fitted(.)),
             na.action = na.exclude)

org.lsm <- lsmeans(m.lme, "ENTRY_NUM")
YIELD.lsm <- data.frame(summary(org.lsm))

# A function to do the same thing.
Single_yr_fn_Y <- function(Data_1Yr) 
{
  m.lme <- lme((YIELD) ~ ENTRY_NUM,
               data = Data_1Yr, random = ~1|LOCATION/BLOCK,
               na.action = na.exclude)

  org.lsm <- lsmeans(m.lme, "ENTRY_NUM")
  YIELD.lsm <- data.frame(summary(org.lsm))
}

# Each year subset run in the function.
Y1_r <- Single_yr_fn_Y(Y1)
Y2_r <- Single_yr_fn_Y(Y2)
Y3_r <- Single_yr_fn_Y(Y3)
```

On the Mac, the following error message is returned.

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, ncol(ca), value = ca) : 
  wrong number of contrast matrix rows
Called from: `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, ncol(ca), value = ca)
```

On the PC it returns the following warning, but generates output regardless:

```
Warning message:
In qt((1 - level)/adiv, df) : NaNs produced
```

Please note: The Mac does not consistently generate the error message. If it is run multiple times for the same data subset sometimes it generates the same message as the PC (!?!).

Finally, on Mac the debug returns the follow message. I have googled this and only return the GitHub script for the package.

```
  stop("wrong number of contrast matrix rows")
```

You will be my new favorite person if you can suggest a solution!

UPDATE

```
df2<-structure(list(YEAR = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2014", "2015", "2016"), class = "factor"), 
LOCATION = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("DAVIS", 
 "DELTA"), class = "factor"), ENTRY_NUM = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L), .Label = c("1723", "1748", "1766", "1807", "1820", 
"3178", "3179"), class = "factor"), BLOCK = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), PROTEIN = c(NA, NA, 11.17, NA, NA, NA, 11.87, NA, NA, 
 NA, 7.98, NA, 11.87, NA, NA, NA, 11.6, NA, NA, NA, 11.79, 
 NA, NA, NA, 12.06, NA, NA, NA, 13.46, NA, NA, NA, 11.34, 
 NA, NA, NA, 12.41, NA, NA, NA, 13.27, NA, NA, 13.42, NA, 
 NA, 12.45, NA, NA, 12.97, NA, NA, 13.074733, 12.328292, 13.024004, 
 12.922546, 13.58927, 13.125462, 14.277735, 12.987769, 12.364527, 
 12.038412, 12.480479, 13.386354, 13.538541, 13.074733, 13.364613, 
 13.364613, 13.096474, 12.929793, 13.248661, 13.176191, 10.357108, 
 10.378849, 10.871645, 11.118043, 13.813927, 14.263241, 15.922804, 
 NA, 12.712383, 12.734124, 12.400762, NA, 13.582023, 13.176191, 
 13.212426, NA, 11.973189, 11.792014, 11.799261, NA, 12.422503, 
 12.060153, 12.154364, NA, 12.581937, 12.748618, 12.480479, 
 NA, 10.770187, 10.704964, 11.089055, NA, 13.726963, 12.603678, 
 12.915299, NA)), .Names = c("YEAR", "LOCATION", "ENTRY_NUM", 
 "BLOCK", "PROTEIN"), row.names = c(6125L, 6126L, 6127L, 6128L, 
6165L, 6166L, 6167L, 6168L, 6181L, 6182L, 6183L, 6184L, 6541L, 
6542L, 6543L, 6544L, 6581L, 6582L, 6583L, 6584L, 6597L, 6598L, 
6599L, 6600L, 3411L, 3472L, 3533L, 3594L, 3417L, 3478L, 3539L, 
3600L, 3421L, 3482L, 3543L, 3604L, 3439L, 3500L, 3561L, 3622L, 
3899L, 3960L, 4021L, 3905L, 3966L, 4027L, 3909L, 3970L, 4031L, 
3927L, 3988L, 4049L, 501L, 431L, 399L, 445L, 541L, 509L, 397L, 
406L, 427L, 550L, 512L, 402L, 545L, 430L, 515L, 405L, 465L, 416L, 
400L, 558L, 457L, 454L, 553L, 404L, 502L, 546L, 398L, 525L, 905L, 
855L, 843L, 841L, 823L, 821L, 845L, 892L, 932L, 830L, 858L, 867L, 
854L, 847L, 870L, 918L, 904L, 802L, 911L, 812L, 875L, 872L, 895L, 
888L, 930L, 950L, 832L, 893L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the same locale on both systems (e.g. `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C"); Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "C")`)? I observed locale-specific differences in some R packages before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `contrasts<-` error is coming from `lme`, not `lsmeans`.  Also, check to make sure that `getOption("contrasts")` has the same result on both systems. It might help to specify the contrasts explicitly in the `lme` call.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the uncertainty, thanks.

Comment: @David Heckmann. A call to `Sys.getlocale()` returns the following: The Mac: `C/C/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8`. The PC: `LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252`. I am not clear on what this is telling me. Running `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")` & `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "C")` did not rectify the issue.

Comment: @rvl A call to `getOption("contrasts")` on both machines returned the following `unordered "contr.treatment" ordered "contr.poly”`. So, if "contrasts" in lme is the cause what is the reason for the difference between Mac and PC, and how it is rectified?

Comment: I wonder if some level(s) of ENTRY_NUM (or some other factor?) are missing in certain years and if the two systems handle that differently. Another thing I notice is that Data1_Yr is both a global variable and the local variable in your function. If you change the argument (and also the data arg in the lme call) to something else, maybe the behavior will change if it is due to a scoping issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely a scoping issue. I have no reason to believe it has anything to do with PC versus Mac. On my Windows PC, I entered the code you give in the order shown, and here's how it ends:

```
> # Each year subset run in the function.
> Y1_r <- Single_yr_fn_Y(Y1)
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, ncol(ca), value = ca) : 
  wrong number of contrast matrix rows 

> Y2_r <- Single_yr_fn_Y(Y2)
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, ncol(ca), value = ca) : 
  wrong number of contrast matrix rows 

> Y3_r <- Single_yr_fn_Y(Y3)
Warning message:
In qt((1 - level)/adiv, df) : NaNs produced
```

Note in particular that I *do* get the contrasts error message with years 1 and 2, but that I *don't* get the error message (only the warning) with year 3. This happened because the data frame `Data_1Yr` exists in the global environment, and the function is accessing it. Moreover, it was last defined with just year 3, so that's the dataset for which it is right. If I delete that data frame, I get a different result:

```
> remove(list = "Data_1Yr")
> Y3_r <- Single_yr_fn_Y(Y3)
 Error in ref.grid(object = list(modelStruct = list(reStruct = list(BLOCK = -0.92001152041278,  : 
  Perhaps a 'data' or 'params' argument is needed
```

What is happening is that `lsmeans` is unable for some reason to access the dataset within the function body, and it kind of worked when the data was available in the global environment. This appears to be a scoping issue for the `lsmeans` function, and I will look into it. But it is not due to a difference between the Mac and the PC, but rather a difference in what is in your global environment. See the workaround at the end for what you can do with the package as it exists now.

Now, the warning message is important too:

```
> head(YIELD.lsm)
  ENTRY_NUM   lsmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
1       951 6371.463 394.5384  0      NaN      NaN
2      1215 5076.817 394.5384  0      NaN      NaN
3      1375 4960.407 394.5384  0      NaN      NaN
4      1429 4472.692 394.5384  0      NaN      NaN
5      1431 4918.525 394.5384  0      NaN      NaN
6      1440 5956.541 394.5384  0      NaN      NaN
```

You get the warning because there are zero d.f. for your estimates, making it impossible to obtain confidence limits. Look at just one `ENTRY_NUM` level...

```
> subset(df, ENTRY_NUM == "951")
    YEAR LOCATION      LAT      LONG PLOT_NUM ENTRY_NUM BLOCK    YIELD  PROTEIN
37  2016     KERN 35.36958 -119.3332       37       951     3 6650.642 15.50248
67  2016     KERN 35.36958 -119.3332       67       951     4 5967.717       NA
79  2016     KERN 35.36958 -119.3332       79       951     2 6770.654 15.28507
88  2016     KERN 35.36958 -119.3332       88       951     1 6096.838 15.48798
114 2015     KERN 35.39439 -119.3419      136       951     2 4069.434       NA
147 2015     KERN 35.39439 -119.3419       75       951     3 4869.934       NA
180 2015     KERN 35.39439 -119.3419       85       951     4 5844.528       NA
215 2014     KERN 35.13716 -119.0326      198       951     1 6203.077 12.07000
216 2014     KERN 35.13716 -119.0326      192       951     2 6362.791       NA
217 2014     KERN 35.13716 -119.0326      232       951     3 6693.333       NA
```

and what you notice is that there is only one `LOCATION` involved -- hence zero d.f. if you block on it! That's an error in your *model*, not in `lsmeans`. Perhaps what you want is `random = ~ 1 | BLOCK`, but I am not sure. Make sure that you understand correctly how to specify the appropriate model.

#### A workaround

```
Single_yr_fn_Y <- function(data) 
{
    m.lme <- lme(YIELD ~ ENTRY_NUM,
                 data = data, random = ~1|BLOCK,
                 na.action = na.exclude)

    org.lsm <- lsmeans(m.lme, "ENTRY_NUM", data = data)
    org.lsm
}
```

I fixed the random part of the model to something more reasonable. It is not necessary to parenthesize the response variable in the model. The call to `lsmeans` explicitly specifies the dataset to use, which works around the scoping problem. BTW, I didn't see a need to wrap the result in `summary` or `data.frame`, because the `print` method for the result displays just what you want to see. Here's the first part of the result for year 1:

```
> Single_yr_fn_Y(Y1)
 ENTRY_NUM   lsmean       SE df  lower.CL upper.CL
 878       7100.395 335.3031  2 5657.7021 8543.088
 951       6419.734 335.3031  2 4977.0407 7862.427
 1166      7184.060 335.3031  2 5741.3672 8626.753
 1210      7911.242 335.3031  2 6468.5490 9353.935
    . . .
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I don't disagree. I should have said that I knew that the data was incomplete. In hindsight, this data was not the best choice.  Even when all years have data, but there are still missing replicates, it will run on a PC, but on a Mac it still generates  the error message `Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, ncol(ca), value = ca) : 
  wrong number of contrast matrix rows
Called from: `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, ncol(ca), value = ca)`. I attempted to upload a new dataset but I don't have enough sapce.

Comment: I just added a new data set update above. This has data for every location and year, but some replicates are missing. On a PC, I can generate the PROTEIN.lsm object inside and outside the function. On a Mac it can only be generated outside the function. On a Mac, the `Single_yr_fn_Y` function returns the `contrasts<-` error. Why?

Comment: I explain why if you read my answer. And it is not a difference between a Mac and a PC, it is a difference of what you have stored in your worksheet on those two systems. I also provide a workaround that you can adapt to your needs. But please write your function with a dataset name that differs from anything in your worksheet.

Comment: Enter the `remove()` statement in my answer on your PC, and then you'll get that error in your PC too.

Comment: Lack of attention on my part, sorry. Your solution worked, thanks!